# how to monitor every http request?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, testing, visual-studio-2012, load-testing

How can I monitor the the requests visual studio makes during load test?

fiddler didn't help and I don't see a proper vs window to do it? I want to snip all the requests and responses.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio requires that you manually configure a proxy for a WebTest. Follow these instructions to set the proxy for your test: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff400220.aspx. By default, Fiddler runs on `http://127.0.0.1:8888`.

Note that you will want to keep Fiddler minimized while running the load test to help minimize the cost of updating the UI while the test is running.

Answer (score 1):

[Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) is a proxy tool that does a good job of sniffing and logging http/https requests.

Comment: There's nothing that Charles can do that Fiddler can't. The problem he's encountering is that Visual Studio does not, by default, run its load test through the proxy.